# Use ampersand to targets parent selectors

Tags: html, css, less

I read a few of the ampersand topics, but I can't find solution for my issue. This is the output CSS I'm trying to achieve:

**CSS**

```
.box-item__info--normal,
.box-item__info--left {
    padding-left: 11px;
    padding-right: 11px;
}
.box-item__info--normal h4,
.box-item__info--left h4 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
.box-item__info--normal .item-price {
    float: right;
}
```

Then, I write this LESS syntax:

```
.box-item{
    &__info{
        position: relative;
        padding: 35px 0 15px 0;

        &--normal, &--left{
            padding-left: 11px;
            padding-right: 11px;

            h4{
                font-size: @delta;
            }

            & , & .item-price{
                float: right;
            }
        }

        &--left{
            padding-top: 20px;

            h4{
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Will produce:

```
.box-item__info--normal,
.box-item__info--left {
    padding-left: 11px;
    padding-right: 11px;
}
.box-item__info--normal h4,
.box-item__info--left h4 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
.box-item__info--normal,
.box-item__info--left,
.box-item__info--normal .item-price,
.box-item__info--left .item-price {
    float: right;
}
```

How can I make this code work as I expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Less code will achieve what you are looking for:

```
.box-item{
    &__info{

        &--normal, &--left{
            padding-left: 11px;
            padding-right: 11px;

            h4{
                font-size: 1.5em;
            }
        }

        &--normal{
            & .item-price{
                float: right;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You cannot achieve the last rule using the double rule `&--normal, &--left{..}`, because this would affect `.box-item__info--left .item-price` too